# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) in Node.js and nginx

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, nginx

I am testing a sample node app using nginx.

But I get 504 Gateway Time-out. nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu 14.04)

I saw others posts related to the same topic but its of no use.

Below is the procedure which I followed for installing node, nginx on Azure.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
curl -Lo hello.js http://do.co/node-hello
sudo nano app.js
```

**app.js file**

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('Came here');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');


ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 265 Mar 12 15:52 app.js

sudo npm install pm2 -g
pm2 startup
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup upstart -u azureuser --hp /home/azureuser

pm2 start app.js


Nginx Server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

**sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm; 

    server_name testingnode.cloudapp.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://13.65.148.35:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

sudo service nginx restart
```

**http port 80 is opened in azure dashboard**

[image]

So after all configurations trying to run http://13.65.148.35/ or testingnode.cloudapp.net will give 504 timeout.

Please let me if anything needs to be configured for running node with nginx.

Comment: Can you try deleting the lines `root /usr/share/nginx/html; index index.html index.htm;`? Also, what happens if you `curl http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: Basically, your nginx is running and can be connected to from the outside, but something's going screwy between it and node. If you definitely can connect to node on your server locally, your nginx settings are likely wrong

Comment: @MattFletcher when I run curl http://localhost:8080 it gives Hello World.
I commented the lines which you mentioned but still 504

Comment: Okay, try changing the `proxy_pass` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: I reckon that nginx is trying to do the proxy path by almost "jumping out" from the server rather than locally, and if you don't have 8080 open to the world, it'll never be able to reach it

Comment: changing the proxy_pass to http://127.0.0.1:8080 works.
But give me half an hour i'll check once more and get back to you

Comment: Ah that's good, I can see "Hello world!" now too. I've put it as an answer, if you're still having any problems let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your nginx config, change the line `proxy_pass http://13.65.148.35:8080;` to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;`

You're providing the externally accessible IP to the proxy pass, so nginx will conform to the firewall settings in the same way that an external user would; that is, not be able to access port 8080. Make sure it's communicating within the local scope of the server.